# Android how to clustering markers on map v2

Tags: marker, markerclusterer

I am writing an apps about google map v2
i have around 6000 makers to add into the map,
and to hide and show them with the camera change,
and also on info window click event include.

I have done the above functions, but i have no idea on how to clustering the markers,
as i search in GOOGLE, i found that there is a library call CLUSTERKARF, it works,but i got some problem on it,
I dont know how to change the markers' icon, infowindow function disabled....

Do anyone of you had working on that library? or maybe another library or method that i can use?